# Can I install a single shut off valve to turn off both hot and cold waters in my apartment?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shutoff

I am doing bathroom renovation and need to install main shut-off valves for the apartment. Previous owner just have two shut-off valves sticking out of the wall below tub spout which is ugly. The plumber said he can move them to be under the sink.

As the space is limited under the sink, I am thinking is there a valve that with a single switch and can shut off both hot and cold water? Anyway if I ever want to shut off the water supply to the apartment I would like to do that for both hot and cold water instead of just one of them.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like a double-valve (that hot and cold would go through) that is actuated with one single handle?  I've seen washing-machine hookups like this but nothing made for in-wall installation on the main water supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a dedicated shut off valve for both hot and cold. You will also have a shut off valve for the entire apartment located at your water meter. This will allow you to cut off all of the water in your apartment.